# deploy openbravo in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, openbravo

I have tried to deploy `Openbravo` with tomcat using web browser.

It throws me

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space exception
```

I tried to increase memory by adding the following parameters in the Java Options space

```
-Xms512m
-Xmx2048m
-XX:PermSize=512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

After adding the above parameters, tomcat service is not get starting. Showing me error.

Please let me know, how to deploy the `openbravo` with tomcat in web browser.

Answer (score 1):

http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/Installation/Troubleshooting#Out_of_memory

To avoid “Out of memory” complaints during building OB you must add options '-Xms384M -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M' to both ANT_OPTS and CATALINA_OPTS environment variables.
Notes on editing environment variables

To make changes in environment system-wide you should put its assignations into a file and place it in /etc/env.d, carefully checking precedence and possible overwritings.
Bulbgraph.png       Do not forget to run env-update after making any changes into /etc/env.d!

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue add the following properties in your tomcat parameters.

For Instance Startup add the following properties in tomcat6w window (double click tomcat6w under bin folder of tomcat) and select Java tab

```
              -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
              -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled
              -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
              -XX:PermSize=128m
              -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

**Maximum Memory Pool -- 3052**

For Windows 7 Instance Start up add the following properties in
tomcat6w window (double click tomcat6w under bin folder of tomcat) and select Java tab

```
              -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
              -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```